# PDOStatement is "stuck" when a resultset throws a SIGNAL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this sample code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test_sql',
        'root',
        '',
        array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$pdo->query('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tst');
$pdo->query('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tst2');
$pdo->query('CREATE FUNCTION tst() RETURNS VARCHAR(5) BEGIN RETURN \'x123456\'; END');
$pdo->query('CREATE PROCEDURE tst2() BEGIN SELECT tst(); END');

$st = $pdo->prepare('CALL tst2()');
try {
    $st->execute();
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
    $st->closeCursor(); // same with unset($st)
    var_dump('This is never executed');
}
```

So it's a `PROCEDURE` (tst2) that returns a single resultset, in which I call a `FUNCTION`. But that `FUNCTION` is (somehow) broken since it returns a data too long for its `RETURNS` clause.

When I run this file, I get the expected result:

```
string(93) "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'tst()' at row 1"
```

But my problem comes afterward: the PDOStatement seems "broken", and when PHP tries to garbage collect it, or when I try to `closeCursor()` (so I can do other queries again), or when I try to `unset` it (for the showcase), then PHP got stuck. It never reaches the other var_dump, it just... got idle for ever?!

I've got this problem on PHP 5.6.35 but also on 7.1.16 and 7.2.4 (all using mysqlnd driver 5.0.5 or 5.0.12). I'm using MySQL 5.7.21 (I did not try on other MySQL versions).

Any clue?

---

Meanwhile, I've also also tried without using prepared statements (so using `$pdo->query`) and even using `mysqli` functions: same issue, PHP is stuck.

But, by changing the content of the procedure so it does not try to return a resultset where the `SIGNAL` occurs, PHP is no longer stuck. So this will "work" (work = I get the SQL exception in my code and my PHP script is not frozen)

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test_sql',
        'root',
        '',
        array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$pdo->query('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tst');
$pdo->query('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tst2');
$pdo->query('CREATE FUNCTION tst() RETURNS VARCHAR(5) BEGIN RETURN \'x123456\'; END');
$pdo->query('CREATE PROCEDURE tst2() BEGIN SET @x := (SELECT tst()); END');

$st = $pdo->prepare('CALL tst2()');
try {
    $st->execute();
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
    $st->closeCursor(); // same with unset($st)
}
var_dump('end');
```

In fact, it seems that since the SQL error occurs inside a resultset, PDO gets the result set headers from MySQL, then gets the exception and so it stops there, and never "closes" the resultset (statement would be left "opened", awaiting for data that will never come).

---

Seeing all of these, I've reported the bug to PHP team, because I got the same on mysqli and PDO, with any PDO option, and on a very specific case

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76815

Comment: Once a database exception occurs then don't try and and be clever and try and help the database to cleanup. The database engine will sort out the mess. All you can do is quit this operation. I would wrap all this code in transaction. In the 'catch' just rollback. Otherwise commit.  It may be possible to continue using the connection. It really depends on what the database error was.

Comment: @RyanVincent I can't even do that since when PHP garbage collects the `$st` statement, then it will also stuck. If you try that code, your PHP process will look frozen (even outside Apache, in PHP as a CLI). Same if you comment out the `closeCursor`.

Comment: No exception thrown here, only `string(22) "This is never executed"` if moved outside of the `catch` block.

Comment: `PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2018 13:50:25) ( NTS )`
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB , for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: It's abnormal if you have no exception at all because PDO should rethrow the SQL error. Maybe it behaves differently on Maria than on Mysql (I also tried on OVH's server, and on a Linux too, at PHP got stuck on the closeCursor untill you KILL the connection from another MySQL client)

Comment: Same with `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2` and `PHP 5.4.39-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2015 08:33:29)`. Works without problems.

Comment: Then it might be a mysqlnd driver issue (since it occurs also on mysqli, and that mysqlnd was used on all my environment checks). Still, you should always have the exception raised. Did you used MariaDB on that 2nd test?